# HTML, Script different input text but submitted as one

Tags: javascript, html, forms, tabular

You might asking why would you do this?
My actual code, is very complicated than this one, Lets just say I made it difficult enough for me, since these inputs are separated in different columns of table the table,
and I'm trying to submit all the input of text value.

```
  <form id="myForm" action="form_action.asp">
   First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
   Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
   Nick name: <input type="text" name="nname"><br>
   In Game name: <input type="text" name="iname"><br>
    </form>
        <?-----separate information ----?>
    <form id="myForm" action="form_action.asp">
    Username: <input type="text" name="uname"><br><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit form">
    </form>

     <script>
     function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
    }
    </script>
```

And I know this code is not working the way I want it to work.
What is other possible way to do this?
[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_form_submit)

Comment: It's not working? Did you link to the w3schools css in your test page? <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">

Comment: You don't submit multiple forms, you need to combine them into a single form. I mean, they are even pointing to the same `action`/destination. Maybe you need to reevaluate what it is that you are trying to do. So, what is it that you are actually trying to do with separate forms posting to the same place?

Comment: ID is supposed to be unique in the document. So, you can't have multiple elements with same ID. Add all those input fields in the same form. You will get them together in the back-end. If you want them separate, you'll probably have to manipulate data and form JSON object using form data and submit the data using ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have multiple `<form>` tags with the same ID. You can include anything you want inside a form tag, so I'm not sure why you thought you needed to break it up... but it's unnecessary and likely what is causing your issue.

You can also get rid of the JavaScript entirely by using the proper type button for the submit button.

```
<form id="myForm" action="form_action.asp">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  Nick name: <input type="text" name="nname"><br>
  In Game name: <input type="text" name="iname"><br>

       <?-----separate information ----?>

   Username: <input type="text" name="uname"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit form"/>
   </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  ******?><form method='POST'><?php
>                 echo "
>                 <tr>
>                 <td><input type='text'  name='LNS' value='$row0[1]' style='width: 100.2222204208374px;'></td>
>                 <td><input type='text'  name='FNS' value='$row0[2]' style='width: 100.2222204208374px;'></td>
>                 <td><input type='text'  name='CRS' value='$row0[3]' style='width: 60.2222204208374px;'></td>";
>                 if($row0[4] == "1"){
>                     $str=$row0[4].'st Year';
>                 }else if($row0[4] == "2"){
>                     $str=$row0[4].'nd Year';
>                 }else if($row0[4] == "3"){
>                     $str=$row0[4].'rd Year';
>                 }else{
>                     $str=$row0[4].'th Year';
>                 }
>                 echo"<td>
>                 <input type='text' value='$str' style='width:75.2222204208374px;'></td>";?>
>                 <td align="center" style="border-right-width: 10px;padding-right: 0px;padding-bottom: 0px;padding-left: 0px;padding-top: 0px;">
>                 <div class="image-holder" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-left: 0px;padding-top: 0px;padding-bottom: 0px;padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">
>                 <img class="thumbnail" src="phone.png" style="width:32px;height:32px;">
>                     <div class="dropdown" style="left: 0px; width: 300px;bottom: 100px;left: 50px;">
>                         <div class="dropdown-content" style="width: 300px;background-color: #E6E6E6;">
>                 <?php
>                 $q1 = "SELECT DISTINCT StudentNumber FROM `studentno` JOIN`students` ON studentID_FK=$row0[0] ";
>                 $r1 = mysqli_query($connection,$q1);
>                 echo "<b>$row0[1]'s Contact Numbers</b>";
>                 if(mysqli_num_rows($r1) > 0){
>                 while($ro1 = mysqli_fetch_row($r1)){ 
>                     echo "<form method='POST'>
>                     <input type='hidden' name='ID' value='$row0[0]'>
>                     <input type='hidden' name='SS' value='$row0[6]'>
>                     <input type='text'  name='Number' value='$ro1[0]' 
>                     style='width: 136.2222204208374px;'>
>                     <input type='submit' name='CHNGStdn' id='edit-icon'  alt='Submit'></input>
>                     <input type='submit' name='DELStdn' id='delete-icon' alt='Submit'></input></form>";
>                     }
>                     echo "<form method='POST'>
>                     <input type='hidden' name='ID' value='$row0[0]'>
>                     <input type='hidden' name='SS' value='$row0[6]'>
>                     <input type='text' name='Number' value='New'
>                     style='width: 136.2222204208374px;'>
>                     <input name='ADDStdn' type='submit'  id='add-icon' alt='Submit'></input><br></form>";
>                     }else{
>                     echo "<form method='POST'>
>                     <input type='hidden' name='ID' value='$row0[0]'>
>                     <input type='hidden' name='SS' value='$row0[6]'>
>                     <input type='text' name='Number' value='New'
>                     style='width: 136.2222204208374px;'>
>                     <input name='ADDStdn' type='submit'  id='add-icon' alt='Submit'></input><br></form>";
>                     }?>
>                 </div>
>                 </div>
>                 </div>
>                 </td>
>                 <?php 
>                 echo "<td><input type='text'  name='ADDR' value='$row0[5]' style='width: 136.2222204208374px;'></td>";?>
>                 <td>
>                 <?php
>                 $q2 = "SELECT ParentID, LastName_Parent FROM `parents`";
>                 $r2 = mysqli_query($connection,$q2);
>                 if(mysqli_num_rows($r2) > 0){
>                     echo "<input type='text' style='width: 136.2222204208374px;' name='ID' value='LastName'>";      
>                     while($ro2 = mysqli_fetch_row($r2)){
>                         echo "";    
>                     }
>                 }echo "</td><td>";
>                     echo "
>                     <input type='hidden' name='IDS' value='$row0[0]'>
>                     <input type='hidden' name='SS' value='$row0[6]'>
>                     <input type='hidden' name='YR' value='$row0[4]'>
>                     <input type='submit' name='CHNGStd' id='edit-icon' alt='Submit'></input>";
>                     ?></form><?php******
> ```

Comment: Doesn't work as you asked.
[link] (https://scontent.fmnl4-4.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-12/16651997_1378110272212084_939059435_n.png?oh=c2334c02257f9b097cd7f44ee91d4870&oe=589F2449) it turns out like this in the browser.